# Spring Role OAuth Authentication Api Issue

Tags: php, curl, oauth

I want to consume [Spring Role api](http://docs.springrole.apiary.io/) but unfamiliar with OAuth authentication process.
It demands a step to authenticate and get access token first .

I don't know what should be the REDIRECT URI
and how will I receive my access token to give an actual call to the api feed service

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you sign up on https://springrole.3scale.net/, you should get a `client id`. And you should also set a `redirect_url` of your choosing.

Now when you make that first request to `https://api.springrole.com/authorize?scope=PLAN_ID&redirect_uri=REDIRECT_URI&response_type=token&client_id=CLIENT_ID`

The user will be sent to the SpringRole login screen, and after they have successfully logged in, it will redirect to your `redirect_url` and in the http url query parameter you will get your `access_token`.

You should test this out in your browser to see it in action.

Comment: But I have to integrate more than one apis like this once at a time , It just contradicts the requirement of my app. By the way thankyou for your valuable reply. It will be helpful for me later.